# UIScrollView showing up as blank screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I'm trying to make a Scroll View that can page through different colored backgrounds.  As of right now, when I attempt to go to that Scroll View, the backgrounds don't show up, leaving me with nothing but a blank screen and no scrolling capabilities.  I've spent hours looking online for a solution to this, but nothing seems to work.  This is the implementation for my ImageViewController class:

```
- (void)loadView
{
   [super loadView];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; 
}
```

Comment: You're adding `scrollview` as a subview at the end, but setting `self.scrollview` throughout.

Comment: good catch, however [self.view addSubview:self.scrollview] didn't work either.

Comment: How do you initialise self.scrollView?  What is its frame before this code runs?

Comment: Oh and move this code out of your `loadView` method and perhaps into `viewDidLoad` instead. Right now you're setting the subview frames and scrollView content size based on a scrollview frame that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: both viewWillAppear and viewDidLayoutSubviews cause it to crash and give the SIGABRT error. is it a connection problem in the interface files? I'd post a picture, but I'm new to the forum and I'm not allowed

Comment: scrollView is declared in ImageViewController.h as @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView; is that what you mean when you ask how it's initialized?

Comment: Did you remove the [super loadView] line?

Comment: yes, I removed that line.

Comment: I don't think it's related to your error, but if you want to post that code in  viewWillAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLoad, you're going to have to modify your code since those methods could be called multiple times.

Comment: As well as declaring it in the .h, you need either to initialise it in code (with alloc/init or similar), or to hook it up in the storyboard.  Are you doing either of those?

Comment: I hooked it up to the .xib file. I must be hooking it up wrong though, because i get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ImageViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.' ---I'm confused though, because it looks like the view outlet is set. It's greyed out, so I couldn't disconnect it if I wanted to.